# Best way to iterate through which report groups a user belongs for security and speed

Tags: python, django

I have a model for User (Django Built-in), Reports, ReportGroups and ReportGroupMembers. A User can create a Report, that belongs to a single ReportGroup.  The user can only write reports for ReportGroups they belong (hence ReportGroupMembers).

In my view (below), I'd like to only show groups the user owns or is a member of and have a decorator or someway to easily prevent people from writing to groups they don't belong.  ReportGroups *can* have a password associated (which is used to join a group).  I'm not too sure the best way to design/accomplish this and have it scale well.  If I didn't need it to scale I'd just for loop iterate through groups they belong.

View:

```
owned_group_list = ReportGroup.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
member_group_list = ReportGroupMember.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
group_list = owned_group_list | member_group_list
return render(request, 'dashboard/main.html', {'group_list': group_list})
```

This does not work above as it complains about "Cannot combine queries on two different base models."

Model:

```
class ReportGroup(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'report_group'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Group: %s - User: %s' % (self.group_name, self.user.username)


class Report(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=False)
    users = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.OneToOneField(ReportGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'intelligence_report'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.name, self.users.username)


class ReportGroupMembers(models.Model):
    groups = models.ForeignKey(ReportGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    users = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'report_group_membership'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Group: %s - User: %s' % (self.groups, self.users)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
owned_group_list = ReportGroup.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
member_group = ReportGroupMember.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
group_list = ReportGroup.objects.filter(
    Q(id__in=member_group.values_list('group_id')) | Q(id__in=owned_group_list.values_list('id')))

return render(request, 'dashboard/main.html', {'group_list': group_list})
```